# Nfs mount cause the server to stuck

Tags: mount, nfs, vxworks, allegro

In my project, I am trying to mount 2 directories that I configured on the server.

I don't know in advance that both of the directories exist on the server side, The server also does not know, It is a question of current deployment.

What I see is that if I try to mount the non-existing directory first, the server is not allowing me to mount the existing directory and gets stuck.

I have 2 threads. The first thread is trying to mount the existing directory on the server whereas the second one tries to mount the non-existing one.

What I expect to see is that even when one mount fails other mount (With valid exports and folders exist) should succeed.

What I see is that the order of mount calls is important.
If the first attempt fails then the server will now allow mounting the existing folder as well

Can you help me figure out how to use it so a non-existing mount will not defect the second try to mount an existing one?

NFS v3
Server: AllegroNfs
Client: VxWorks 6.9.3 using nfsDrv lib

Thanks in advance.

Nir Azkiel

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `What I see is that the order is important.` IS the order of execution important? And what is the order of execution?

Comment: The question lacks clarity, please reframe the question if possible.

Comment: Hi, What I ment to say is that the order of mount operations changes the server behaviour. . If The first mount is to a non existing folder at the server then the server get's stuck and failes to.mount the second mount command to the existing folder.The server has 2 exports, the client trys to mount both of them, but the deployment is not alwayes the same and it can happen that 1 export folder will not exist and I need the client to be able to mount the other existing one.

Comment: Excellent. Edit your question with the same clarity as in your comment.

Comment: OK, fare enough, Done.

Comment: `What I see is that if I try to mount the non-existing directory first, the server is not allowing me to mount the existing directory and gets stuck` Does it get stuck forever or does it timesout after some amount of time? Also is it possible to check if server is alive (e.g. by pinging etc.) before attempting to mount it?

Comment: Previous comment was on how to prevent the locking if possible. Now, the problem (what I think it is anyway) is that VxWorks threads execute based on their priorities. If both of your threads have the same priority, one of the threads will stay on execution until it goes to a pending state. In your case, it probably gets stuck trying to reach the server and never gives way to the other thread. You can check this by executing `i` command from the Command Shell. Result would be a dump of all threads, their states and priorities. You should add it to the question for others to be able to help you

Comment: I tryed putting a mutex lock around it. Each thread had the chance to execute the mount. So it is something else. after somethung like 15 seconds the mount will return with timeout but it will be the same with the exist folder as well. I also tryed to test it on windows with a nfsClient application and it looks the same. a non existing folder mount cause the allegroNfs server to stuck. If I check the "Disable persistent file handlers" option on the nfs server it behaive as I expected but then I am not protected against server restarts.